# Arrayformula & Counta

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Goal: a formula in row P2 that counts instances of data from F2:M2 that is also populated down all of P.  [Here's the example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/103ubDtQV6XDUJv7GcswRIjYwYE79kGkmT0phUpBi2Bk/edit?usp=sharing)

I have been trying to get an array formula that does it so that if I want to change things I can just edit P2 instead of doing that all the way down.

Comment: Can't access sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Hello! I tried to open the example, but it is not set to public. Could you please update it, so I could take a look?

Comment: So sorry about that. Fixed.  Sheet is public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    1 / ( 1 / 
    countif( sign(len(F2:M)) & "-" & row(F2:M), "1-" & row(F2:M) ) 
  ) ) 
)
```

Comment: Wow. This very much works. Any chance you could help me understand it? I've been breaking out the pieces but don't see how they fit together.

Comment: The formula does a row-by-row count by matching row numbers with row numbers with the condition that the values on the row must have a non-zero length — i.e., `sign(len(F2:M))` returns `1`. The result is the count of such values row-by-row. The `iferror()` wrapper gets a blank result on rows where there are no values.